Loki is taking too long time to load items in Explorer and on Grafana dashboards
I have been experiencing an issue with Loki as a datasource in Grafana. When I check the explorer page in grafana, it often takes a long time to load filenames, jobs, labels, and other elements. Sometimes, it even fails to load completely.
In the image, you can see the spinner continuously revolving in the "select label" section. It keeps moving for an extended period.

This is my loki config file:
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096
  http_server_read_timeout: 300s
  http_server_write_timeout: 300s
  http_server_idle_timeout: 300s

common:
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093

query_scheduler:
  max_outstanding_requests_per_tenant: 4096

frontend:
  max_outstanding_per_tenant: 4096

query_range:
  parallelise_shardable_queries: true

ingester:
  chunk_idle_period: 15m  # This increases the idle period before flushing a chunk
  max_chunk_age: 2h  

limits_config:
  split_queries_by_interval: 5m
  max_query_parallelism: 64
  max_streams_per_user: 30000
  max_global_streams_per_user: 0

And this is my loki service file:
[Unit]
Description=Loki service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=loki
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/loki-linux-amd64 -config.file /usr/local/bin/config-loki.yml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I am using these versions:

loki 2.4.7_4


Grafana Version 10.1.1

How can I resolve this issue? I feel that Loki is slowing down in completing their tasks.

The reason I found for this issue is high memory or CPU usage. Please consider upgrading your hardware to ensure smoother operation.
After the upgrade, the spinner doesn't revolve as much, and things load in a very short time.
